# Automatically copying dependencies from other directories with make

Tags: makefile, rules, cp

I have a makefile with multiple targets that are generated by copying a file from outside the working directory.

```
a.tex   : $(wildcard /foo/work1/a.tex)
    cp -p $< $@

b.tex   : $(wildcard /foo/work2/b.tex)
    cp -p $< $@
```

I use `$(wildcard)` because sometimes I run Make on systems that do not have access to `/foo`.

What is the best way to avoid repeating the `cp -p $< $@` commands for every rule? Some options:

- Setting up a `%.tex : %.tex` rule. This works, but it also applies to targets that aren't specifically indicated so I get lots of warnings like `make: Circular a.tex <- a.tex dependency dropped.`
- Defining a sequence of commands with `define`. This seems pointless since the command is only one line. So instead of copying `cp $< $@` to every rule, I'd define a `cp-dep` sequence and copy `cp-dep` to every rule.
- Defining the command as a variable so that I could do `a.tex   : $(wildcard /foo/work1/a.tex); $(CP-DEP)`
- Duplicating the target names as an additional rule. `a.tex b.tex : ; cp -p $< $@`. Error-prone.
- Just copying and pasting. Clunky but effective and easy to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing this:

```
COPYFILES = /foo/work1/a.tex /foo/work2/b.tex

define copyrule
$(notdir $(1)): $$(wildcard $(1))
    cp -p $$< $$@
endef
$(foreach file,$(COPYFILES),$(eval $(call copyrule,$(file))))
```

The advantage of this method is that I can easily add new files with a minimum of boilerplate text and I can easily copy the rule part of this to a new Makefile. The disadvantages are that I can no longer change the destination filename, and the implementation is rather opaque for people with less makefile experience.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tested it, but can't you just use a pattern rule without prerequisites, and specify the prerequisite for each target on a separate line?

```
a.tex: $(wildcard /foo/work1/a.tex)
b.tex: $(wildcard /foo/work2/b.tex)

%.tex:
    cp -p $< $@
```

Btw. doesn't the wildcard function return the empty string when it doesn't find a match, so that `$<` is empty as well? Wouldn't that give a problem with `cp`?

Comment: That doesn't work. The pattern rule doesn't put anything in `$<`. When `$(wildcard)` returns an empty string, the target is perceived as up-to-date, so nothing happens when the dependency isn't available on a system.

Comment: @Michael: That's odd; I tried it and it works for me. Are you using a different make than me? I use GNU make.

Comment: @MichaelHoffman: Do you mean that `$<` is empty *even when the dependency is available?* And what do you want Make to do if the dependency is not available?

Comment: @eriktous: My mistake: I tried it again and it does seem to work. Must have been a problem with the test code I came up with last time. Only thing I don't like about this is that it will generate a `%.tex` rule for files that I haven't explicitly defined dependencies for which lead to confusing results. @Beta: if the dependency is not available, I don't want Make to do anything.

Answer (score 2):

I think your `copyrule` is overkill (and inflexible). If your objection to @eriktous's solution is that it will apply the rule to targets for which you haven't explicitly defined dependencies, that's easy to fix with a [static pattern rule](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern):

```
a.tex: $(wildcard /foo/work1/a.tex)
b.tex: $(wildcard /foo/work2/b.tex)
blue.tex: $(wildcard /some/other/path/green.tex)

TEXES = a.tex b.tex

$(TEXES): %.tex:
    cp -p $< $@
```

(If this solves your problem you should accept eriktous's answer-- this is just a variation on it.)

Comment: A nice thing about this solution is that it isn't limited to just `%.tex` files. But it still results in me having to type lots of boilerplate.

Comment: @MichaelHoffman: Lots of boilerplate? You said you want a rule only for targets for which you haven't explicitly defined dependencies, therefore you have to type in the dependencies. This solution also requires you to add the name of a new target to the `TEXES` line. How much less do you want to type?